# User defined variables in Gitlab CI environment URL empty

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the following (simplified) `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  APP_NAME: "hello-gitlab-ci"
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: some-script
environment:
  name: staging
  url: http://hostname/$APP_NAME/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
```

The resulting url in the Gitlab UI is e.g.: `http://hostname//master`. `$APP_NAME` seems to resolve to an empty String, whereas the runner variable `$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME` resolves correctly.

GitLab Community Edition 8.13.0, gitlab-runner 1.7.1.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

From [GitLab doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#yaml-defined-variables), the YAML-defined variables are supported with GitLab Runner 0.5.0 or higher and GitLab CI 7.14 or higher, so first, check your GitLab component versions.

Try also enabling debug, to have more clues on why this variable is not resolved:

```
job1:
  variables:
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
```

Comment: GitLab Community Edition 8.13.0, gitlab-runner 1.7.1

Comment: @user449326 OK. What OS are you running on? Does CI_DEBUG_TRACE yields any interresting details?

Comment: The debug output has no occurrences of `environment` or `url`, except `WARNING: environment is not supported by selected executor and shell` but a quick research revealed that this seems a common warning, that can be ignored. Where the environment variable occurred it was resolved correctly as in `++ export APP_NAME=hello-gitlab-ci ++ APP_NAME=hello-gitlab-ci`

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a bug in GitLab Runner where the env variables are defined after the environment but before the script. Have you considered opening an issue? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues

Answer (score 1):

GitLab variables are not translated specifically in the environment section of .gitlab-ci.yml. There are a few issues open regarding this (and the lack of documentation regarding this), e.g. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27921

Answer (score 0):

This is now (6 years later) supported with [GitLab 15.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#use-nested-cicd-variables-with-environments-in-pipeline-configuration) (May 2022)

> ### Use nested CI/CD variables with environments in pipeline configuration
>
> Using CI/CD variables with the `environments` keyword in your CI/CD configuration is great, because it lets you [create environments dynamically](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#create-a-dynamic-environment). While this is already a powerful feature, there were still some limitations, because you could not use nested variables to define environments.
>
> Starting in GitLab 15.0, you can nest variables inside other variables, and have them all expand the way you expect. This makes dynamic environments even more powerful due to the increased flexibility!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_0/environment.png -- Use nested CI/CD variables with environments in pipeline configuration]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environment) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/293674).